# .htaccess rewrite pretty URL without affecting default page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website `www.example.com` which loads the default `index.php page`. I also have a `login.php` which I have set this rewrite rule for.

It all works fine however when I try to access `www.example.com` it redirects me to `login.php`.

I want to keep the rules in place without affecting the default page. 
Please see below. If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

```
# ensure permalink when url rewriting was enabled (login.php?r=content/perma&id=6 => /content/perma/?id=6

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=content(/|%2)perma&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}/content/perma/?id=%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/login.php [L]
```

Comment: Change last rule to `RewriteRule . login.php [L]`

Comment: Hey thanks @anubhava! That did the trick. If you want to post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
# ensure permalink when url rewriting was enabled 
# (login.php?r=content/perma&id=6 => /content/perma/?id=6

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=content(/|%2)perma&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}/content/perma/?id=%2 [R=302,L]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . login.php [L]
```